# C# Timer-Crop farming game error

Tags: c#, timer

I have a short question about timers. In my code I want to create a crop farming game, with a timer that shows if the plant is finished.
Why does this:

```
    public static string currentPlant;
    public static Timer growTimer;
    public static void InitGrowTimer( int time, string name )
    {
        growTimer = new Timer();
        growTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(growTimer_Finished);
        growTimer.Interval = time;

        currentPlant = name;
    }
    public static void plantCrop(string crop)
    {
        if (plantActive == false)
        {
            if (plants.Contains(crop.ToLower()))
            {

                // growTimer.Interval = <plant>Time;
                // proceed plants
                switch (crop.ToLower())
                {
                    case "wheat":
                        InitGrowTimer(wheatTime, wheatName);
                        growTimer.Start();
                        break;

                    default:
                        MessageBox.Show("FATAL ERROR\nThe plant is contained in the definition list but not in the plant menu!", "Civilisation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This plant is not available!", "Civilisation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("There is already a plant in progress! Current plant: {0}", currentPlant);
        }
    }

    private static void growTimer_Finished (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        growTimer.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Your " + currentPlant + " is finished!", "Civilisation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
```

not start the timer, or just doesnt show the messagebox at the end. What am I doing wrong at creating the timer or creating the tick event?

EDIT: This is my main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeLists();
        // game begin
        Farm.plantCrop("wheat");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Write("Please enter your desired name: ");
        QC.resetColors();
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(/*Introduction*/"Welcome to the world of Civilisation. In this world it is your choice what\n" +
                                          "you are up to. You can be a farmer, miner or fighter, whatever you want, the\n" + 
                                          "world is yours to explore! Have fun!"
                                          );
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();

        while (true) // run game
        {
            // menu
            Console.Write("         What do you want to do?\n" +
                          "Farm    Mine    Explore    Go to the city\n"
                          );
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (menuContent.Contains(input.ToLower()))
            {
                if (input.ToLower() == menuContent.ElementAt(0))
                {
                    // farm
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("-- Farm --\nSelect a crop to plant:");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                    int icount = 0;
                    for ( int i = 0; i < Farm.plants.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (icount < 3)
                        {
                            Console.Write(Farm.plants.ElementAt(i));
                            Console.Write("\t\t");
                            icount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("\n");
                            icount = 0;
                            Console.Write(Farm.plants.ElementAt(i));
                            Console.Write("\t\t");
                            icount++;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    QC.resetColors();
                    string crop = Console.ReadLine();
                    Farm.plantCrop(crop);
                }
                if (input.ToLower() == menuContent.ElementAt(1))
                {
                    // miner

                }
                if (input.ToLower() == menuContent.ElementAt(2))
                {
                    // fight

                }
            }





        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `growTimer.Start();` is called? In debug mode with a breakpoint or with logging.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault yes it is, with the values growTimer {Interval = 2000}, wheatTime = 2000

Comment: Where are you calling `plantCrop("wheat")`?

Comment: @phoog immediatly at the beginning of `static void Main(string[] args)`

Comment: @IanH. Can you post the entire main method?

Comment: @phoog I just edited it. I am calling the `plantCrop("wheat")` from the beginning atm because I wanted to test if it works.

Comment: Erm it's a console app, not a winform. Are you able to see _any_ message boxes? Try to trigger your "FATAL ERROR" one. Pretty sure it won't pop up.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I dont know actually. It is my first time using messageboxes in a console application...
edit: I just tried it. `MessageBox.Show("test");` works fine.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault just tested it. It doesnt even enter the growTimer_Finished event. But messageboxes work fine atm.

Comment: If you hover over "Timer" (the class name), does it say "System.Windows.Forms.Timer"?

Comment: Are you planting other crops?

Comment: Pretty sure you're using it, so I added an answer.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault maybe thats the main reason, can't use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` inside a Console Application. [Timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says it must be used in a window.

Comment: Now you start with games, and the problem about threads and tasks, its on your door, I also recommend you to read about [Parallelism in .Net 4](http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/), doesn't change a lot from 4 to 4.5, thats one of great series I found on the Web. As @Pierre-LucPineault answer also is based on `System.Threading` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` timer is made for a Windows Form app with a single UI thread.

You need to use the `System.Threading.Timer` timer instead for your console application.

It's creation and the parameters of the callback are a little different:

```
    public static void InitGrowTimer(int time, string name)
    {
        growTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(GrowTimer_Finished, null, time, Timeout.Infinite);
        currentPlant = name;
    }

    private static void GrowTimer_Finished(object sender)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your " + currentPlant + " is finished!", "Civilisation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
```

You do not need any `Start`method, it will be started automatically on creation.

You don't need a `Stop` either; it will run only once because of the `Timeout.Infinite` parameter.

You can replace `null` with the object you want the callback to receive, if needed (i.e. what would have been in `EventArgs`).

---

Little side note: I've renamed your callback method in PascalCase. Per convention, the methods in C# should always start with a capital letter.

Comment: Are you sure he should be using `System.Threading.Timer` as he's calling WinForms `MessageBox.Show`?

Comment: Ahh that makes sense I will test it first thing tomorrow. And I am writing in camelCase because that's what we use in our shop lessons.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thats another problem, update UI from another thread. Thats way I recommend him to read about [Parallelism in .Net 4](http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/).

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't see what could be the problem with having both a Threading timer and Winform MessageBox. The project itself should be a Winform, or he shouldn't rely on Windows.Forms for a console app, but it will still work in this current state. Can you elaborate on your point?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - I know for sure that creating/updating UI from a non-UI thread is bad. I'm not sure if the same is true for `MessageBox`, but using `System.Threading.Timer` might be a bit of problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity It's a console app, not a Winform. There's not really a notion of `ui` and `non-ui` that applies here.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - Since `MessageBox` is in `System.Windows.Forms` I wasn't sure if it did or not.

Answer (score -2):

Because you, as you tell yourself, do not start the timer.

```
growTimer = new Timer();
growTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(growTimer_Finished);
growTimer.Interval = time;
growTimer.Start();
```

Comment: It's started right under the `InitGrowTimer` method call.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault could that be the problem maybe?

Comment: @Ian No. Moving the `Start` line into the method won't change anything. It's called immediately after exiting `InitGrowTimer`. Unless you're trying to start your timer from somewhere other than `plantCrop`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that. What is the value of wheatTime